# Write out a script to /usr/local/bin that uses $@ via a script in bash

Tags: linux, bash, alias

I have a bash script that is writing out a file to /usr/local/bin that needs to take in additional parameters.

I'm trying something like this:

```
  echo "PYTHONPATH=/opt/script_folder/$TIMESTAMP /opt/script_folder/$TIMESTAMP/script -param <param_value> $@" | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/script_alias
```

I want the user to be able to use this by running `script_alias -second_param <second_value> ...` and the script picking up the second parameter.

However, the `$@` is pulling in every param I pass to the shell script writing out the /usr/local/bin file.  I tried escaping the `$` to `\$@` but the `$@` is not being written out.  Any thoughts on why?

Comment: To quote the bash IRC factoid database: "If you have to ask, use a function instead". Aliases are prefix substitution -- just simple string replacement; that's all they can do.

Comment: (That means that when you use `"$@"` or `"$1"` or any other reference to command-line arguments in an alias, you're not referring to the arguments that the alias was passed, but the arguments that were already set _before_ you called the alias; the alias doesn't have its own stack frame, so it doesn't have its own argument list).

Comment: My challenge is that there are values I want to pass into the bash script to hardcode into the alias/function but then I want it to also take additional command line arguments.  Do you know where I can learn to do that?

Comment: `args=( "$@" )` will store your current argument list into an array, so you can have a function have its own argument list but be able to refer back to that array. BTW, aliases don't work in scripts at all.

Comment: I'm considering a different tactic where I set a global alias with the text in the echo.

Comment: bash doesn't have any such thing as a "global alias". Are you actually thinking about zsh instead?

Comment: Okay, this is now a duplicate of a _different_ question as it's been edited; you need to use single quotes if you don't want things expanded before they get to `echo`.